# Можно ли в PhpStorm настроить показ изменений по сравнению с основной версией файла в git репозитории?

Tags: git, phpstorm, netbeans

Раньше пользовался NetBeans. Перешел на PhpStorm и со временем понял, что очень не хватает данного функционала.

Пример и доки:

```
-Синий - Обозначает строки, измененные по сравнению с более ранней версией.
-Зеленый - Обозначает строки, добавленные к более ранней версии.
-Красный - Обозначает строки, удаленные по сравнению с более ранней версией.
```

[image: example]
<sub>(источник: [netbeans.org](https://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/74/ide/git/left-margin.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если указать, что [в проекте используется git](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/enabling-version-control.html), все изменения сразу начинают показываться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/file-status-highlights.html#2

Только, не совсем понятно, что вы называете "основной версией". В PhpStorm показываются изменения по сравнению с *предыдущей* версией. Сравнить с произвольным коммитом тоже можно, но для этого отдельный интерфейс.

Comment: хм.. спасибо. На белом фоне как то не бросалось в глаза

Answer (score 1):

Такой функционал в PHPStorm есть из коробки.

Чтобы им воспользоваться, нужно перейти в Settings -> Version Control. PhpStorm сам подскажет есть ли у Вас репозиторий для данного проекта. Просто выделяете его в списке и под списком жмете на плюсик.

После этого программа начнет показывать изменения в файлах аналогичным с указанным Вами способом.